# Is the fixed point set of a self-diffeomorphism of odd order orientable?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Let $M$ be a smooth oriented manifold and let $f \colon M \to M$ be a self-diffeomorphism with $f^p = \text{id}_M$ for some odd $p > 0$. Then $f$ is orientation preserving and it follows from the slice theorem that the fixed point set
$$
F = \{ x \in M : f(x) = x\}
$$
is a smooth submanifold of $M$. Is $F$ orientable?

Comment: I posted this question on Mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253811/is-the-fixed-point-set-of-a-self-diffeomorphism-of-odd-order-orientable

Comment: **Please** next time you want to do that, tell the mods and we can *move* the question to MO rather than copy it